# Unbelievable fast battery discharge on some games

Tags: battery-life, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I've submitted an issue about my phone crashing: [Issue Link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/63612/samsung-galaxy-s4-crash-on-some-games) which nobody here was able to help understand and resolve.

Now I have better observations: after starting a game with almost full battery, and about 5 minutes of gaming, my device after connecting to charger shows 15% of battery. It means that 80% of battery was gone within 5 minutes of gaming!

Is it really possible that some heavy dynamic graphic game drains the battery to this extent, or is it  physical damage of the phone? Other than games applications on my phone seems to function normally, for example Endomondo will discharge phone to null after running about 5 hours in background.

Comment: Just a quick note: this isn't an issue tracker, so you haven't "submitted an issue". This is just a Q&A site where Android users try to help each other when we can. We're not associated with Google or any manufacturer. If you want to "submit an issue" so it can be fixed, try one of the resources listed in [Where can I report a bug?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/47680/12442)

Comment: @DanHulme I know it's not issue tracker, I've just asked here my issue.

Comment: That's good. I just wanted to be clear because some people get confused and think this site is some kind of bug tracker where they should complain about Google or Android, or expect that mentioning a problem here will get it fixed.

Comment: Oh, now I see many people have problem with Samsung Galaxies :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer lies in your question itself, you have mentioned that other than games the phone runs normally! I think its the games that are causing this, anyway to make sure of that please read ahead.

Can you specify if it is one particular game or all games? If it is just the games mentioned in the other link you have provided, can you just try with the following games and let me know how it goes?

- [Temple Run 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.imangi.templerun2)
- [Subway Surfer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kiloo.subwaysurf)

The games you have mentioned Paradise Island and Dragon City are really heavy games!

Also do you play with the charger connected or disconnected? This was unclear from your question.

Comment: when charger is connected games don't crash, but with disconnected crash quick, but anyway i can't believe it should be possible to fully discharge battery in 10 minutes, no matter how heavy the game would be

Comment: Any chance you tried the games mentioned above?

Comment: @FolksLord it really sounds like you have a weak battery, which does not make a lot of sence for such a newer phone. Unless it was cooked (li-ion prefers room temps) or a knock-off , or the connection is not so good.  You could reconnect the battery, check the  connection points.

Comment: @AadiDroid I've played a bit Temple Run 2, about 10 minutes, without crash. About 10% battery is away.

Comment: You mean you lost only 10% of battery charge ?

Comment: @AadiDroid update: Temple Run 2 crashed in about 5 minutes, when I've switched to Usain Bolt (charger disconnected). Maybe I'll have to play only by charger connected....

Comment: Good battery test! Battery was bugged, after changing it the following games helped me to test it and make sure, a new one is good!